help to intuit or propose mechanisms in bioorganics
I would like to receive some advice on how to intuit the stages in biochemistry / biochemistry reactions.
I have difficulty “seeing” the abrupt jumps in biochemical pathways.
The mechanisms of organic chemistry I understand very well, but as far as biochemistry is concerned, I sometimes find it difficult to intuit these “jumps” of enzymatic transformations to continue the pathway.
I give an example: (propose a scheme to go from Orsellinic acid to Penicillinic acid)

The answer in my book is this:

As you see, I would not even have thought of going through quinol. Once I get there I am able to intuit the next steps. But the first step would not even occur to me. Well, the same thing happens to me with many exercises.
Can you give me some advice on how to propose the mechanisms in such situations?

A general trend is that biochem uses a lot of carbonyl chem and simple redox (+/- H2). One-electron chemistry is relatively rare except when using O2 for oxidation.

Well, it's not a "first step", but at least two of them.

It depends a lot on the shape of the active site of the enzyme, what amino acids are involved in the steps (eg. catalytic triads), what cofactors the enzyme uses, even the biological environment. You can find general trends for them but specific steps are usually extremely difficult to reason out without direct observation.

also, the best approach is usually to work backwards (retrosynthesis) just as you would when working out a chemical synthetic pathway. In this case, opening the lactone should be obvious, and then you have a hexane derivative, so closing those six carbons into the ring you need in the starting material is a good bet.  The methyl group is likely to remain unaffected since it's in both SM and product, so use that to assign position of carbons in final product
